# How to create a complete package (.exe) windows application

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms

I have to create an project( **windows Application** on invoicing ) which also include Database (Sql server) .
Now i want to create an **complete package** for client machine .
This package includes the following :

1. .net framework required to run on Client machine
2. IIS
3. Sql server Database
4. Application itself.

   if .net framework already installed on client machine it can skip installing.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create installer for your application. VS2012 does not contain setup project, but if you use older version you may create this (setup project with custom actions). Also you may look at Wix or other third party installer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply budy.Is ClickOnce Deployment is good to use or not.

Comment: ClickOnce is a good technology but it's bad customizable. You can not create database or files during installation process. More info http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/

Comment: it means if we create a Database for our application it is not available after setup is installed.

Comment: If you need run sql sripts at installation process you should create custom installer (Wix or something else). Or you can do it at application first start but it's bad way:) With ClickOnce you can add local database like access, sql compact, sqlite etc.